# Is there a way to redirect in php only if a variable meets a specific condition?

Tags: php, if-statement, redirect

I have something like

Is this possible?

```
if(this works){
echo "this works";
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
}else{
echo "it didnt work";
header( "refresh:5;url=somewhereelse.php" );
}
```

Comment: No, but only because you do an `echo` before you attempt to do the `header()` you cannot send headers to the browser AFTER you have send any of the page. echo will start the process of sending data to the page

Comment: so how would you do this?

Comment: By the way thanks for the help I've received from you all these questions I've had

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but only because you do an echo before you attempt to do the header() you cannot send headers to the browser AFTER you have sent any of the page. `echo` will start the process of sending data to the page as will anything, even a space before your `<?php` would do that

But assuming you have no other output sent to the browser before you run this code you could do

```
if($sometest){
    header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
    echo "this works";
}else{
    header( "refresh:5;url=somewhereelse.php" );
    echo "it didnt work";
}
```

However in reality the echo would never get to the browser (current Page) as you are redirecting to another page, so you can just do

```
if($sometest){
    header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
}else{
    header( "refresh:5;url=somewhereelse.php" );
}
```

If you really have to see the message you woudl have to add it to the querystring of the redirected pages, or put it into the SESSION and the then the redirected pages would have to look for the message and send it as part of their page content.

Comment: ok so this would still send the message? right?

Comment: No, added a bit extra on that subject

Comment: ok so it works. I can send the message after the url change. and it will show because I have it change only after 5 sec. Thanks

Comment: @KadenSkinner - If this answer solved your issue, you should accept it so others can see the issue has been solved.

Comment: I had to wait 5 mins. During that time I did some work. I marked it as solved

Comment: I had a new problem with this question so I updated it.

Comment: Might be worth asking a new question rather than couching 2 in a single question. Tends to make the answers that once looks ok, now look wrong and that wont help others understand whats going on